# calculating correct memory utilization from invalid output of pidstat

Tags: linux, performance, bash

I used, `pidstat -r -p <pid> <interval> >> log_Path/MemStat.CSV &`  command to to collect the memory stat. 
after running this command I found that RSS VSZ %MEM values are increased continuously, which is not expected, as pidstat provides the the values considering the interval.

After searching on net I found that there is bug in pidstat and I need to update the syssat package. 
(please refer last few statements by pidstat author on this link : http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/tutorial.html)

Now, my question is, how do I calculate the correct %MEM utilization from the current output as we cannot run the test again.
sample output :

```
Time        PID    minflt/s majflt/s    VSZ     RSS     %MEM
9:55:22 AM  18236   1280    0       26071488    119136  0.36
9:55:23 AM  18236   4273    0       27402768    126276  0.38
9:55:24 AM  18236   9831    0       27402800    162468  0.49
9:55:25 AM  18236   161     0       27402800    169092  0.51
9:55:26 AM  18236   51      0       27402800    175416  0.53
9:55:27 AM  18236   6859    0       27402800    198340  0.6
9:55:28 AM  18236   1440    0       27402800    203608  0.62
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Sysstat tutorial page you refer to it is said:

> I noticed that pidstat had a memory footprint (VSZ and RSS fields)
>   that was constantly increasing as the time went by. I quickly found
>   that I had forgotten to close a file descriptor in a function of my
>   code and that was responsible for the memory leak...!

So, the output of `pidstat` has never been invalid; on the contrary, the author wrote

> pidstat helped me to detect a memory leak in the pidstat command
>   itself.